# Use of files on hard drives instead of url with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to modify this script to use offline files, if I download the files from url works, but if the same file as I withdraw from hard drives, does not open, someone helps me to understand why and how to do, thank you.

```
    def INDEX():
    TVLIST('https://www.*********/playlist/*******/test.m3u')


def TVLIST(url):
    try:
        m3u = getHtml(url)
        parsem3u(m3u)
    except:
        addDir('Nothing found', '', '', '', Folder=False)
    xbmcplugin.endOfDirectory(int(sys.argv[1]))

urlopen = urllib2.urlopen
Request = urllib2.Request

def getHtml(url, referer=None, hdr=None, data=None):
    if not hdr:
        req = Request(url, data, headers)
    else:
        req = Request(url, data, hdr)
    if referer:
        req.add_header('Referer', referer)
    if data:
        req.add_header('Content-Length', len(data))
    response = urlopen(req)
    if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    buf = StringIO( response.read())
    f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
else:
    data = response.read()    
response.close()
return data

def parsem3u(html, sitechk=True):
    match = re.compile('#.+,(.+?)\n(.+?)\n').findall(html)
    txtfilter = txtfilter = GETFILTER()
    txtfilter = txtfilter.split(',') if txtfilter else []
    txtfilter = [f.lower().strip() for f in txtfilter]
    i = 0
    count = 0
    for name, url in match:
        status = ""
        url = url.replace('\r','')
        if not txtfilter or any(f in name.lower() for f in txtfilter):
            if sitechk:
                if i < 5:
                    try:
                        siteup = urllib.urlopen(url).getcode()
                        status = " [COLOR red]offline[/COLOR]" if siteup != 200 else " [COLOR green]online[/COLOR]"
                    except: status = " [COLOR red]offline[/COLOR]"
                    i += 1
            addPlayLink(name+status, url, 3, uiptvicon)
            count += 1
    return count
```

I thought, was enough to put the local path

```
def INDEX():
TVLIST(r'c:\Desktop\IPTVLIST\M3U\playlist\test.m3u')
```

who explains why it does not work and how can I do? Thank you

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: You can probably use a `file://` URI. Cf. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/

Comment: the script of the answer is  Nothing found no error log

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works well

Comment: In this way, on windows, it works perfectly, but if the script you use Android, the memory load path, can you tell me if it is equal  TVLIST('file://c:/Desktop/IPTVLIST/M3U/playlist/test.m3u')

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @languitar in the comments you would have `file://` which of course it should work for windows, but moving to a platform like android, you have different file system there, you don't have `C` drive. So make sure you got an alternative location on the android.